# Showing equivalence of group members

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Let $G$ be a group, $x,y \in G, \text{ord } x = 5,\ x^3y = xy^3$. Show that $xy = yx$.

I tried to reform $x^3y$ and $xy^3$, but all I got was $yx^3x^3x = yxy$.

Can you please help me to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$x^3y=xy^3\implies x^2=y^2\implies \begin{cases}xy=x^6y=(x^2)^3y=(y^2)^3y=y^7\\{}\\yx=yx^6=y(x^2)^3=y(y^2)^3=y^7\end{cases}$$

Comment: thank you for your answer! The only thing I don't understand is your first step, how do you get from $x^3y = xy^3$ to $x^2=y^2$?

Comment: @muffel $$x^3y=xy^3\implies x^2y=y^3 \implies x^2 = y^2$$

Comment: @muffel Cancelling elements, which is **always** possible in a group: $\;ax=ay\implies x=y\;$